# What was the titular glitch?

Tags: glitch

With its third season, the show [Glitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch_(TV_series)) has ended. The series followed the path of a couple of people who had come back from the dead.

By the end, viewers were not given an explanation on how the phenomenon happened after all<sup>1</sup>. Now I'm wondering:

**What exactly does the title "Glitch" refer to?**

Was the entire story (starting with the first returned) a glitch of the universe? Was it every return from the dead that was considered a glitch? Was the title maybe even chosen during the early stages of planning when the nature of the phenomenon was still being debated by the producers, and something where the title "glitch" could be fitting was being considered (think "virtual environment with the glitch of dead characters coming back")?

---

<sup>1</sup>: Not at last because the two major opinions about the nature of the phenomenon - a cosmic imbalance that must be corrected at all cost vs. a scientifically interesting process that must be analyzed and may or may not be repeated without any inherent repercussions - never got a chance to get properly juxtaposed and compared due to the shady behaviour of the people involved on both sides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title was chosen (from a range of titles) to indicate that *something* had gone wrong.

> Even the name is a departure from the more gothic, old-school names
> favoured by the French and American productions. The word ‘glitch’
> conjures up images of computers and technology, but **at its most basic,
> it simply tells you that there’s been an error.** “We really looked for
> another one, but we couldn’t find anything that was in some ways as
> blank as ‘Glitch’. **Every time we put another title on, it was just too
> heavy-handed and it loaded the show up too much.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[“It’s going to be a challenge, and ambitious, but I feel up for it”: an interview with Lou Fox](https://popculture-y.com/2015/08/interview-lou-fox/)</sup></sub>

In true Lost/Happening fashion, there was no explanation for what happened, even after the show had resolved.

Comment: "there was no explanation for what happened" - nor whether anything *had* indeed gone "wrong". As I mentioned in the question, the proposed explanations or possible workarounds were not really given a chance within the limited screentime.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I think the implication is that even had they had seven seasons and a movie, they wouldn't have revealed the cause of the glitch because doing so would diminish the series.

Comment: "because [revealing the cause of the glitch] would diminish the series" - I guess I'll never understand (let alone agree with) that reasoning, but this answer is probably the most verifiably accurate explanation we are going to get, so I'll accept this.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - The reasoning is that if you avoid having an explanation, you can keep changing the rules